# $_GET not providing me correct content

Tags: php

I have a url with danish language in yii framework like:
           mylocal/paservice/product/værktøjer-til-industrirobotter

but when I Print `$_GET` I get this : `prodcut/vÃ¦rktÃ¸jer-til-industrirobotter`

how I can get 'værktøjer-til-industrirobotter' as it is in url?

there is any php function for this?

Comment: set utf-8 in  header also you can try url_encode and url_decode

Comment: Odds are, you're not setting the right Content-Type header before printing that string, which makes your browser display that text in the wrong charset.

Comment: this is already in header `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the correct character encoding when outputting the text. Try using UTF-8 by adding something like this at the start of the file:

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");

Answer (score 1):

You have to use encode url to generate link and after getting data in `$_GET` decode the variable.

PHP has functions for this tasks. `rawurlencode()` and `rawurldecode()`